# How do i get errors in from a Perl script running FCGI.pm to appear in the Apache error log?

Tags: perl, apache, error-logging, fastcgi

As follows is an example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use FCGI;
my $request = FCGI::Request();
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    die "test";
}
```

I'd expect this to print "test" to the Apache error log, [as per FCGI spec](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch1intro.htm#8066), but instead nothing at all happens. If i move the die outside and in front of the while loop, the message is printed to the error log.

Further info regarding Apache configuration, this line is used to configure the handler:

```
Addhandler fcgid-script .fcgi
```

I am told that suexec is in use and acts as fcgi wrapper.

---

**Edit:**

A partial solution is brought up by [FCGI.pm itself](https://metacpan.org/module/FLORA/FCGI-0.74/FCGI.PL):

> no die and warn handlers are installed by default. This means that if you are not running an sfio enabled perl, any warn or die message will not end up in the server's log by default. It is advised you set up die and warn handlers yourself. FCGI.pm contains an example of die and warn handlers.

As such i tried it in this manner:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use FCGI;
use IO::Handle;

my ( $stdin, $stdout, $stderr ) = ( IO::Handle->new, IO::Handle->new, IO::Handle->new );
my $request = FCGI::Request( $stdin, $stdout, $stderr );
my $err_handler = sub { print {$stderr} @_ };

while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    $SIG{__WARN__} =  $SIG{__DIE__} = $err_handler;

    warn "test1";
    die "test2";
}
```

The `test2` appears in my error log without any issues, however the `test1` does not.

Comment: So the `die` works if moved just beyond the while loop?  The obvious answer, then, would be that your while condition is never true.  i.e. `$request->Accept()` is never `>= 0`.

Comment: Nope, it's not that. If i replace the die in the while loop with a simple print, and hit it with a browser the result is as expected.

Comment: I am confused. Where does the die work?

Comment: Directly before the while loop.

Comment: From the FCGI::Request documentation, you can specify an error file when you create the object. http://search.cpan.org/~skimo/FCGI-0.67/FCGI.PL

Comment: As i wrote, the intent is to have the errors appear in the apache error log.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23509/discussion-between-mithaldu-and-dan1111)

Comment: Any reason why you're not using CGI::Fast?  I can confirm that it takes care of this for you; warn and die write to the server log without any special handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue with a FastCGI client written in Perl, FCGI.pm produces expected output. Perhaps there is an issue with mod_fcgid.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket             qw[];
use Net::FastCGI::Constant qw[:type :role];
use Net::FastCGI::IO       qw[read_record write_record write_stream];
use Net::FastCGI::Protocol qw[build_params dump_record build_begin_request_body];

use warnings FATAL => 'Net::FastCGI::IO';
use constant TRUE  => !!1;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 5)
  or die qq/Could not create a listener socket: '$!'/;

my $host = $socket->sockhost;
my $port = $socket->sockport;

defined(my $pid = fork())
  or die qq/Could not fork(): '$!'/;

if (!$pid) {
    close STDIN;
    open(STDIN, '+>&', $socket)
      or die qq/Could not dup socket to STDIN: '$!'/;

    require FCGI;

    my $r = FCGI::Request()
      or die qq/Could not create a FCGI request: '$!'./;

    while ($r->Accept >= 0) {
        print "Perl: $] OS: $^O FCGI: $FCGI::VERSION\n";
        warn "test1";
        die "test2";
    }
    exit(0);
}

close $socket;
$socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => 'tcp', PeerHost => $host, PeerPort => $port)
  or die qq/Could not connect to '$host:$port': '$@'/;

write_record($socket, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST, 1, build_begin_request_body(FCGI_RESPONDER, 0));
write_stream($socket, FCGI_PARAMS, 1, build_params({}), TRUE);
write_stream($socket, FCGI_STDIN, 1, '', TRUE);
while () {
    my ($type, $request_id, $content) = read_record($socket)
      or exit;
    warn dump_record($type, $request_id, $content), "\n";
    last if $type == FCGI_END_REQUEST;
}
```

**Output**:

```
{FCGI_STDERR, 1, "test1 at fcgi-die.pl line 35.\ntest2 at fcgi-die.pl line 36.\n"}
{FCGI_STDERR, 1, ""}
{FCGI_STDOUT, 1, "Perl: 5.014001 OS: darwin FCGI: 0.74\n"}
{FCGI_STDOUT, 1, ""}
{FCGI_END_REQUEST, 1, {0, FCGI_REQUEST_COMPLETE}}
```

Comment: You were sort of right that things were odd. The issue was that i had an old FCGI.pm installed.